# How to use pip3 with pypy3

Tags: python-3.x, installation, module, pip, pypy

I need to use pip3 to install a package called "pocketsphinx" on pypy3. I have never done this before and therefore totally clueless on the procedure. I am doing this on a raspberry pi. Can anyone help me?

UPDATE:
I tried this:

```
pypy3 -m ensurepip3
```

and I got this:

```
/usr/bin/pypy3: No module named ensurepip3
```

So I tried this:

```
pypy3 -m ensurepip
```

but I got this:

```
ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python.

Python modules for the system python are usually handled by dpkg and apt-get.

    apt-get install python-<module name>

Install the python-pip package to use pip itself.  Using pip together
with the system python might have unexpected results for any system installed
module, so use it on your own risk, or make sure to only use it in virtual
environments.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to run this in a virtual environment. This my first time using pypy3, however I am familiar with python3.

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu have an usual way to package Python for their distributions. You might want to install pypy yourself and not rely on the one distributed in default Ubuntu/Debian _apt_ servers, maybe with this technique: https://askubuntu.com/a/1121758. Or you might want to follow this advice: https://askubuntu.com/a/834798

Comment: @sinroc I'm sorry to say that this didn't work.